# Android center of view in other view

Tags: android, view, position, center

[image]

I want to positioning the blue square like above picture, the center of blue view is on the corner of the other view. How to do that?

Comment: It is not clear from your question that whether are u using layout in xml or canvas. If you are using canvas, then it can be easily done through some calculation in onDraw() method of view and using canvas.

Answer (score 6):

Try this layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/main_widget"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
android:focusable="true" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_width="60dip"
    android:layout_height="60dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/image_border"
    android:contentDescription="image"
    android:scaleType="center" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_count"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="-10dip"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/icon"
    android:background="@drawable/badge_count2"
    android:contentDescription="badge"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="1"
    android:textColor="@color/White"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:visibility="visible" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

### OutPut:

[image]

You just need to change `TextView` with some `ImageView` as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

There is multiple solutions you can use RelativeLayout or FrameLayout.

Have a look at RelativeLayout : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html

Try something like :

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<TheRedView
    android:id="@+id/idRed"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="half of the idBlue width"
    android:layout_marginRight="half of the idBlue height"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

<TheBlueView
    android:layout_width="fixed width"
    android:layout_height="fixed width"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```